# Meteor packages: jquery-validation. How to add value to "submit" when the "input" tag are completed correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

Whether it is possible to add to the tag html:

```
<button type = "submit" value = "Submit" class = "btn btn-success submit"> Save </ button>
```

value: `data-toggle = "tab"`

when:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered (function () {
   $ ("#add") .validate ();
});
```

Returns "true" meaning all the "input" are completed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use `.attr()` to set an attribute and value in the `submitHandler` of `.validate()`:

```
Template.myTemplate.onRendered (function () {
   $ ("#add") .validate ({
     submitHandler: function(form){ // only runs if form validates
       $ (".btn") .attr ("data-toggle","tab")
     }
   });
});
```